# Using the Google Graphs API with dynamic data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-analytics, google-visualization

Just managed to grab some data from the Google Analytics service for my admin dashboard. This is the format it's in when sent to the browser (JSON encoded).

```
[["20161207","11"],["20161208","9"],["20161209","15"],["20161210","2"],["20161211","4"],["20161212","1"],["20161213","3"],["20161214","10"],["20161215","5"],["20161216","4"],["20161217","3"],["20161218","1"],["20161219","2"],["20161220","5"],["20161221","1"],["20161222","3"],["20161223","1"],["20161224","2"],["20161225","0"],["20161226","0"],["20161227","0"],["20161228","0"],["20161229","1"],["20161230","4"],["20161231","2"],["20170101","1"],["20170102","1"],["20170103","4"],["20170104","0"],["20170105","2"],["20170106","4"],["20170107","0"],["20170108","0"],["20170109","0"],["20170110","0"],["20170111","0"],["20170112","0"],["20170113","0"],["20170114","0"],["20170115","0"]]
```

I then want to display it in a chart through JavaScript. My code is below:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      function drawChart() {
$.get("api.php", function(response, status){

t = [];
response = JSON.parse(response);
            for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
                t[i] = [response[i][0], response[i][1]];
            }
});

        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(t);

        var options = {
          title: 'Company Performance',
          hAxis: {title: 'Year',  titleTextStyle: {color: '#333'}},
          vAxis: {minValue: 0}
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.AreaChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="chart_div" style="width: 100%; height: 500px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I'm getting absolutely nothing back. The graph is adapted from [this example](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/areachart) in the docs. The response, for some reason, just does not seem to be valid as an array so I need that extra loop in, although that brings up a blank page, no errors. If I hard-code it, it works. Does anyone have any ideas what could be the problems?

** Latest code **

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart()
{
    $.ajaxSetup({
        cache: false,
    });

    $.get("api.php", function(response, status)
    {
        t = [];
        response = JSON.parse(response);
                for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++)
                    t[i] = [response[i][0], response[i][1]];

        alert(response);
    });

        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Name', 'Number'],
        response,
    ]);

    //data.addColumn('string', 'Employee Name');
    //data.addColumn('string', 'Employee Name123');

    var options = {
        title: 'Company Performance',
        hAxis: {title: 'Year',  titleTextStyle: {color: '#333'}},
        vAxis: {minValue: 0}
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.AreaChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
}
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="chart_div" style="width: 100%; height: 500px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try adding a row of column headings before loading the data rows -- any errors in the console?

Comment: Just tried this now ... when using the 't' array, I got these errors:

CrossPageChannel: Can't connect, peer window-object not set

Line 775
Error: CustomError: Error in protected function: Configuration error when load

Line: 215
Error: Not an array

After using 'response' instead, I only get the last error once.

Comment: Latest code in question above

Comment: Ok, now create a new DataTable directly, instead of passing nothing to arrayToDataTable

Comment: Tried doing this now, and for some reason, despite when using the alert() the data appears, but later down I'm getting a 'response' is undefined error??

Latest code above again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just noticed the second column is encoded as a string,
and needs to be converted to a number,
before creating the data table...

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawChart,
  packages:['corechart']
});

function drawChart() {
  var data = [["20161207","11"],["20161208","9"],["20161209","15"],["20161210","2"],["20161211","4"],["20161212","1"],["20161213","3"],["20161214","10"],["20161215","5"],["20161216","4"],["20161217","3"],["20161218","1"],["20161219","2"],["20161220","5"],["20161221","1"],["20161222","3"],["20161223","1"],["20161224","2"],["20161225","0"],["20161226","0"],["20161227","0"],["20161228","0"],["20161229","1"],["20161230","4"],["20161231","2"],["20170101","1"],["20170102","1"],["20170103","4"],["20170104","0"],["20170105","2"],["20170106","4"],["20170107","0"],["20170108","0"],["20170109","0"],["20170110","0"],["20170111","0"],["20170112","0"],["20170113","0"],["20170114","0"],["20170115","0"]];

  var chartData = [];
  chartData.push(['Name', 'Number']);

  data.forEach(function (row) {
    chartData.push([row[0], parseFloat(row[1])]);
  });

  var dataTable = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(chartData);

  var options = {
    title: 'Company Performance',
    hAxis: {title: 'Year',  titleTextStyle: {color: '#333'}},
    vAxis: {minValue: 0}
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.AreaChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(dataTable, options);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```